# InfoPath current() Function in Multi-Lists

Tags: infopath, filter

When you call current() from a multi-selection list, where does it resolve to?  I ask because I need to use it in a complicated filter to control what values are present in the list.  Has anyone used this?  Does anyone have an idea of how I could find out?